# vue 3 - ::v-deep is deprecated

Tags: vuejs3, less

I have this less code for one vue 3 component.

```
<style lang="less" scoped>
::v-deep {
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
```

Let's say the template is this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

My IDE displays me a warning on v-deep: **v-deep is deprecated, consult docs for better; usage without arguments is deprecated since Vue 3.0 alternative**.
The compiler gives an error.

The question is: **how do I define a (base) style for my component**? I'd like to define some common properties, like color, size etc. Also, I don't want to add a class to the parent div element - I'm looking for another solution (if exists).

Thank you.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::v-deep` was replaced by [:deep()](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors).

```less
:deep(*) {
  font-size: 80px;
}
```